# adding user defined unt to other lazarus project

Tags: lazarus

my problem is i successfully adding my defined unit in delphi2.0 project but in lazarus project  i do not know how to enter path of my unit'D:\Lazarus\Pantip' to 
other project.because the explanation in stack overflow did not indicated that where to put it on path editor or other unitfiles(-Fu) meanwhile the name of  project has already in target file name. my question seem to be a silly
one but in thailand there is almost no Delphi or Lazarus  code writer so i have no choice but to consult outsiders for responding  my difficulty.

Comment: You are welcome to ask here, this is the perfect place, and by asking here you are actually help others too, everywhere on the Earth!

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to the "unit path" line (-Fu)  (I assumed "pantip" is part of the path, not the unit name)
[image: Lazarus unit path dialogue]

Simply put the name of the unit in your uses clause